# Find all number which contain '+7' on the beginning

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to find all number which contain `'+7'` on the start.

I thought about `~` but it hasn't worked for me.

```
SELECT * 
from ds_phone 
where number ~ '+7 \d'
```

Comment: `SELECT * from ds_phone where number  LIKE '+7%'` ? https://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_like_clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try LEFT as below-

```
SELECT * 
FROM ds_phone 
WHERE LEFT(CAST(number AS VARCHAR),2) = '+7'
```

Answer (score 2):

One option would be using `substring()` function:

```
select * 
  from ds_phone 
 where substring(number,1,2)='+7'
```

since `number` is an alpha-numeric column, then no need to cast.

Answer (score 0):

you should replace your query to:

```
SELECT * 
from ds_phone 
where number like '+7%s'
```

Comment: Why should he do that?